# Interactive Batch File

Tags: batch-file, dos

How to proceed with an interactive batch file?

Eg.,

DO you want to continue? [y/n]

If 'y' Goto Label1

Else Goto Label2

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the SET command. The following is the DOS command equivalent of the pseudo code you have above:

```
set /p choice=Do you want to continue? [y/n]
if '%choice%'=='Y' goto label1
goto label2
```

Comment: if '%choice%' == 'Y' goto label1
conditional operator. = dint work for me!

Comment: You may also consider adding a /i to the if so the comparison is not case-sensitive.

Comment: Rossel, where should I add the /i? Can you gimme the statement?

Answer (score 4):

Using the choice command, you can specify a set of valid characters and a message:

```
choice /C YN /M "Do you want to continue?"
if errorlevel 2 goto labelno
if errorlevel 1 goto labelyes
```

Answer (score 1):

I know 1 way to do this (like @user3093687 posted)

```
set /p choice=Do you want to continue? (y,n)
if /I %choice%==y goto Label2
if /I %choice%==n goto exit

:Label2
Cls
echo You chose yes

:exit
exit
```

The /I in the second and third line of the batch file makes it so that it is not case sensitive and special characters are ignored (example Y and y will be both read as y.

Comment: `/i` ignores `!` ? Huh? What version of Windows or DOS do you use?

Comment: I am running Windows 10 and when using /I when I type something like y! It will read it as y. Did you try it out?

Comment: of course I did. Worked as expected: `y!` is not `y`. Also Windows 10. Please doublecheck.

Comment: This is my code:                                                                                           echo Hello! My name is %mcnftaibot%. According to my records, your are %ageic% years old and were born on %bdateic%
echo Is this correct?
echo Yes or No?
set /p aibotcorrect=
if /i %aibotcorrect%==yes goto beginaibot
if /i %aibotcorrect%==no goto SETTINGS                                                                                                   When I type Yes! it reads it as yes.....

Comment: I bet, your label `:beginaibot` is the very next line to that code and therefore gets executed if you input a wrong answer. Run it with `echo on` to see, what's being executed: `if /I yes! == yes goto beginaibot`. There is only one way, `yes!` is "identical" to `yes`: you have enabled delayed expansion, so the `!` gets lost at parsing. But that's a parsing thing related to delayed expansion and has nothing to do with `if` or it's `/i` parameter.

Comment: OK. Sorry about that. I have corrected the question.

Answer (score 0):

set /p choice= Do you want to continue? [y/n]
if "%choice%" == "y" (
goto label1
) else goto label2

Answer (score 0):

Most of your guys' answers i like but the most I would do is (for example this code is my way of organization.

```
:Label1
@echo off
color (any color)
title (anything here)

set /p choice=Do you want to continue? [y/n]
IF %choice% == y goto Label2
IF %choice% == n exit

:Label2
cls
echo you chose Yes.
```